How to intergrate Jupiter terminal dexswap in Wordpress?
This is the terminal, scrolling down gives the codes to put in header and body. It also provides the code snippet.
https://terminal.jup.ag/
So I've put
<script src='https://terminal.jup.ag/main-v2.js' />  in my website head
and
<div id="integrated-terminal"></div>  in my website body
The code snippet is inserted like this in a html block:
<script 
    window.Jupiter.init({
  displayMode: "integrated",
  integratedTargetId: "integrated-terminal",
  endpoint: "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com",

});
</script



The Jupiter dex swap is not showing up.
My domain : top-autoservice.nl

You're missing the > in <script> and </script>
